# How to properly format rapidAPI data on a React frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express

I building a project with Node, express and React and I have to use an API from RapidAPI. Currently, it's only rendering the data in JSON format. So how can I get the data from the server coded with node/express and have it rendered to the HTML frontend?

**This is my `server.js` file**

```
const PORT = 8000

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
require('dotenv').config()
const axios = require('axios').default
app.use(cors())


app.get('/team', async (req,res) =>{
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3/teams/statistics',
        params: {
          league: '39',
          season: '2020',
          team: '33'
        },
        headers: {
          'X-RapidAPI-Key': process.env.RAPID_API_KEY,
          'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com'
        }
      };
      
      try {
          const response = await axios.request(options);
          console.log(response.data);
          res.json(response.data)
      } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
      }
})


app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port' + PORT)
})
```

**`App.js`**

```
import React from 'react'

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the fetch request from react app rather than from express server. If you don't want to make the request from front end then make request from express server, store the result and make a route to send that response to your react app.